# Using eval() to set global variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

My code to set a global variable using `eval` is not working. It's as if the assignment is not called at all, but no script errors occur.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            eval('var x = 1;');
            alert(x);
        }, 0);
    });
</script>

<div onclick="alert(x);">Click to see 'x'</div>
```

When the page loads, the alert shows what I expect; it confirms that x = 1. But after that, I click on the div and get a javascript error that `x` is undefined. How do I make `eval` add this variable properly?

Background: The code above is a minimally reproducing example from a project I'm working on where we must execute javascript code during AJAX responses. `eval` works properly most of the time, but this is causing problems.

Comment: Why don't you use `window.x = 1;` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eval runs locally, you're setting a local variable.

To set a global variable, remove `var`;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            eval('x = 1;');
            alert(x);
        }, 0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @asawyer I don't really care. I'm just answering the question. This is the reason the OP's code isn't working

Comment: @asawyer: it's a common way of natural code obfuscation. Some people use some special obfuscating software, another - just hire bad developers.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the evaluated code is javascript to be run when an ajax request completes. The script is generated by the server. But this is correct - the problem was that the javascript was wrong, not the ajax processing. My javascript sense is not good enough to have caught this; thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `window.eval()` to run `eval()` from global scope. This will assign `var` as a variable of `window`, which is what a global variable is: a variable attached to `window`.

... But you really really shouldn't. `eval()` is sandboxed for a reason.

That is not unless you really know what you are doing and trust everything you are receiving through `XMLHttpRequest`. It is one of those chicken/egg things: if you trust the code enough to execute it, it should be programmed well enough to prefix global variables with `window.` to begin with; thus, you should not need to use `window.eval()`.

Besides, unless you are just trying to avoid async headaches by using the more-manageable `XMLHttpRequest` (there's a first time for everything...), you really should just create a script tag, assign it's source, and append it as a child to the head or body tag. Dynamically appending script tags is even faster than using XHR, especially for big scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend setting global variables, but if you *absolutely* have to, use the `window` object:

```
window['x'] = 1;
```

Comment: you can even use `window.x = 1;`

Comment: The javascript is generated by server controls; it's out of my control.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: @tenfour: then file a bug to the server controls' team bug tracker

Comment: Indeed, the problem here is in the javascript generated on the server. Thanks.

Comment: This is a workaround, just removing `var` creates the global. Globals and evals may be bad, but this is not the point of the question

Comment: @Juan Mendes: "but this is not the point of the question" --- It **always** makes sense to tell people about how to do something in a *correct way*. Just blindly answering what OP wants was never a good strategy. OP could learn something only if you explain why it's good or bad.

Comment: @Blender: this is a case of "once I understood the solution, the question became nonsensical." Voting to closed as too localized.

Comment: @JuanMendes: The point of the question is to help tenfour fix the problem, not cover it with duct tape. I have yet to see any circumstance where the server has to set JavaScript variables like this.

Comment: @Blender @zerkms My answer may not fix the problem in its entirety, but it does show the OP why their code wasn't working without using a workaround (`window.x`). I don't know enough (and neither do you) to solve the problem, we now know that because the OP told us that the code on the server is generated and OP has no control over it. Knowing what I told the OP helped them figure out how to go forward. When I ask questions, I'd rather people answer the question instead of making assumptions about why I want to know the answer.

Comment: @Juan Mendes: we didn't make assumptions, we answered to the question "how to initialize global variables". Your point of view is valid, but personally I prefer to learn people how to do in a right way, rather than just answering straightforward in cases, when it's obvious OP might not understand there is another and better solution.

Comment: @zerkms I agree, when I can see a better solution because the OP was clearly misguided. However, I don't think that's the case here. The OP wasn't even responsible for the JS, they just wanted to understand why it wasn't working as they thought it should.

Comment: @Juan Mendes: and this was only known after this answer has been given

Comment: It is completely appropriate to give a direct answer to a perceived wrong question, but many times as in this case the question is only wrong to the reader but perfectly legitimate to another reader, and that is why we have support for multiple answers by multiple contributors. In such case, you should give question feedback while answering.  

I find this question appropriate because I, too, want to know how to assign to global scope for scripts that work *both* on the client and on the server (hence no window), and in my scenario I only know the variable name @ runtime (as a string).

Comment: And, if you want to know why on earth someone would clutter the global namespace with something from eval, *exactly*. My objective is automating the generation of deeply nested namespaces where the name and the existence of the root namespace is unknown.