# Defining variables dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

In a situation where I have something like this code:

```
var variableNames=["thisMonth", "thisDay"];
var variableValues=["February", 17];
```

Is there any way I could go through the array and initiate variables with their corresponding values?  I've tried something like

```
for(var i=0;i<variableNames.length;i++){
    eval("var "+variableNames[i]+"="+variableValues[i]+";");
}
```

But I'm not getting any reults.  Is eval not able to define variables, or are there other problems that exist?  Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to? Use an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167800/using-eval-to-set-global-variables

Comment: As stated above; do `obj[variableNames[i]] = variableValues[i];`

Comment: some explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: @Johan, correct, and that `obj` could be `window`

Comment: @WillP. Could, yes. But preferably not...

Comment: @Johan good point, but it does do what the question asks

Comment: @WillP. There is no reason to settle with a solution just because it works. Polluting the global namespace is known as a bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the variables on an object. If you want to create global variables the following code should work:

```
for (var i=0; i<variableNames.length; i++) {
  window[variableNames[i]] = variableValues[i];
}

//test
console.log(thisMonth); //"February"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You missed a couple of quotes at `"='" + variableValues[i] + "';");`:

```
var variableNames=["thisMonth", "thisDay"];
var variableValues=["February", 17];
for(var i=0;i<variableNames.length;i++){
    eval("var "+variableNames[i]+"='"+variableValues[i]+"';");
}
```

With that correction however, I would warn you against using it cause it's a very wrong way of doing it.

Use Objects, as most here mention.

Comment: Someone had to highlight the error. Maybe OP is just curious, or perhaps a reason for doing so. :)