# Why isn't this ajax returning the expected javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
 var statusCheckUrl = "https://www.mydomain.com/webchat/live?action=avail";
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        url: statusCheckUrl,
        success: function(result) {
           console.log("result is: "+result);
           eval(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
            unavailable();
        },
        timeout: 2000,
        cache: false
    });
```

If I access the url: https://www.mydomain.com/webchat/live?action=avail in my browser, the response looks like this: `var isAvailable = true;`

However, my `console.log` is printing out `undefined` which is obviously not working as expected.

I am running this code from localhost but thought that the crossDomain: true would overcome any cross domain issues?

How can I resolve this and why is it returning undefined in my success function?

EDIT: I have tried what the person below suggested with regards to the eval but it seems that the result value is always undefined, no matter what. Why am I getting undefined as a result of this ajax call?

Comment: Try changing your `dataType` to `text` and see what you get.

Comment: Yep, tried that - I get a cross-domain error.

Comment: For the answer below, I was assuming CORS was enabled on the "mydomain.com" server. If you're running this from localhost, and the remote server allowed origins policy doesn't allow it, the simple answer here is (sorry but) *it's not going to work*

Comment: Ok, so the 3rd party would have to set their Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I wonder why jquery just seems to swallow this error though, rather than raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the AJAX call, but instead that `eval` runs in its own scope. The `var` keyword in the downloaded script is setting a *local variable* which quickly goes out of scope. Instead you want to set a global variable (remove the `var` keyword).

See also: [Using eval() to set global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167800/using-eval-to-set-global-variables)

---

Side comment: Don't execute code you don't have to, especially *dynamically* and *cross-domain*. If all you want to do is get a value - in this case if something is available or not - just return *the value*. (If you're not in control of the script, but it always looks the same, you could always parse it as a string. You may want to write a script which runs at some interval to check and alert you of any changes in their response format, however.)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't edit the response as it's coming from a third party. Do I have any other options?

Comment: @cookiemonster Fair enough, you had "mydomain.com" so I assumed you were in control of it. Why don't you try a regex to parse the returned string?

Comment: And yeah, I realise I shouldn't be executing this code, but it's coming from a third party I have no control over :(

Comment: Do you know why I can't see the 'var isAvailable = true;' text in the result parameter of the response function? I would have thought I could see it there at least?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for cross-domain requests is to make your request in your server side framework (.net, php), parse the info and get what's needed, then use your own response (json, text, whatever) back to the page.

As @Ic. said, you shouldn't be executing the code. Decent security risk there.